# Regex expression to detect a string-number combination that is 10-20 in length and needs to have at least 3 capital letters and other conditions

Tags: regex

As the title says, I need a regex to detect a combination of strings and numbers that is 10-20 in length and needs to have at least 3 capital letters and at least 2 lowercase letters, whilst ignoring any special characters.

**What it should match**

`https://youtube.com/abcDeFF1234|` In this sequence, only abcDeFF1234 should be matched

`sasddasxaDis3fsc|5MkCDXlmvWYLJGxD||sknsnsjsjs` In this sequence, only 5MkCDXlmvWYLJGxD should be matched

`ABCab1asuxhausihx` In this sequence, everything should be matched
'Hey guys check out https://youtube.com/abcDeFFF1234 it's so cool!' And in this sequence, only abcDeFFF1234 should be matched

**What it shouldn't match**

https://gif.com//images/114fds2klcee7e7fb7a/tenor.gif?itemid=1389

DDD<73010825822784709>dd

abcA|CDA1123|

**Additional info**

And if this helps, the regex `/(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=\d*[A-Za-z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{10,20}\b/` already satisfies most requirements but in the case of `sasddasxaDis3fsc|5MkCDXlmvWYLJGxD||sknsnsjsjs` it matches with sasddasxaDis3fsc instead of 5MkCDXlmvWYLJGxD.

Comment: Why don't you try RegexOptions.RightToleft if you are using .net flavor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
\b(?=([a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})(?=([A-Z\d]*[a-z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{10,20}\b
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/7LpoeDndIyZoxN).

Your problem was that the dot in the look aheads should be a character class of the allowable chars, otherwise the look ahead looks *beyond* the end of the term being matched. Eg I changed:

```
(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})
```

to:

```
(?=([a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})
```

Comment: Capture group 1 and 2 are catching extras, like in Sisnsnjsjsjsj8282||5MkCDXlmvWYLJGxD||sknsnsjsjs

Comment: So what? The entire match is your target. If you really want to not capture groups, add `?:` as the first 2 chars inside the brackets to make it a non-capturing group. Eg `(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})`

Comment: Yeah I realized, sorry, I was just being dumb

Comment: If it helps, here’s a link to the non capturing version if the demo: https://rubular.com/r/dZNKMF5m6fckXQ