# Regex for combination of letters and number that is 5-30 letters long, has at least 4 capital letters, 2 lowercase and at least 1 number

Tags: regex

Hey guys I'm new to regex and I want to create 1 single regex that matches with texts that are

- 5-30 letters long,
- have no special characters,
- have at least 4 capital letters,
- have at least 2 lowercase letters and
- at least 1 number.

### Examples: should match

1. `https://stackoverflow.com/Abcde3FGhiDE/Zyx23` should match: `Abcde3FGhiDE`
2. `|a|b|c|AbcdEFGH123|456Ac` should match: `AbcdEFG123`
3. `P A Abcde3FGhiDE Z H` should match: `Abcde3FGhiDE`
4. `ZZ123!Abcde3FGhiDE!123` should match: `Abcde3FGhiDE`

### Examples: no match

5. `<HeLLoWoRlD"123`
6. `|A|b|c|D|E|F|1|`
7. `NULLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLllll 1`
8. `IAMoverTHELIMITTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT3`

Please make it as concise as you can. My attempt ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/w9BMgW/1)):

```
(?=(?:\d*[A-Za-z]))(?=(?:\S*?[A-Z]){4,}\S*?$)(?=(?:[a-zA-Z]*\d))[A-Za-z0-9]{5,30}
```

Comment: This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This looks very much like homework or some coding challenge - you'll learn more by solving it yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I'll provide what I have

Comment: Would that suffice?

Comment: Not bad. Can you also describe how it doesn't work? If not exactly, indicate the test cases it works correctly with and those it doesn't work correctly with?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/w9BMgW/1 if thats what you were asking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to validate password strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142103/regex-to-validate-password-strength)

Comment: This question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/63440383/4299358

Comment: The link that AmigoJack posted contains a regex that matches all but 1 sequences that I have provided, that being <HeLLoWoRlD>123, I have tried inserting the regex that is (?=.*\d) into it, and that didn't seem to work either.

Comment: To clarify, the regex in the given link was \b(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})(?=(?:[A-Z\d]*[a-z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{10,20}\b and what I'm trying to accomplish is to at least has 1 number for it to match, and that regex seems to match <HeLLoWoRlD>123

Comment: Here's the proof if it helps making it any easier https://regex101.com/r/w9BMgW/3

Comment: And unfortunately, no, jdaz, none of the regex provided in that link worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use

```
\b(?=(?:[a-z0-9]*[A-Z]){4})(?=(?:[A-Z0-9]*[a-z]){2})(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9]{5,30}\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=(?:[a-z0-9]*[A-Z]){4})` Assert 4 uppercase chars A-Z
- `(?=(?:[A-Z0-9]*[a-z]){2})` Assert 2 lowercase chars a-z
- `(?=[a-zA-Z]*[0-9])` Assert a digits
- `[A-Za-z0-9]{5,30}` Match any of the listed 5 - 30 times
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wn70zk/1)

Answer (score 0):

5-30 letters long, has at least 4 capital letters, 2 lowercase and at least 1 number

This mignt not be the cleanest but:

```
/^(?=[a-ZA-Z\d]{5,30}$)(?=(.*[A-Z]){4})(?=(.*[a-z]){2}).*\d/
```

Comment: This does not satisfy the "no special characters" condition.
Try
(?=^(([a-zA-Z0-9]){5,30})$)(?=(\D*\d){1,})(?=([^a-z]*[a-z]){2,})(?=([^A-Z]*[A-Z]){4,})

Comment: Oh yeah I missed that. Updating... Also make sure to put the anchor first on yours.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/w9BMgW/6 https://regex101.com/r/w9BMgW/7 Unfortunately, it seems like neither worked

Comment: And if this helps, I found this: \b(?=(?:[a-z\d]*[A-Z]){3})(?=.*\d)(?=(?:[A-Z\d]*[a-z]){2})[a-zA-Z\d]{5,30}\b does everything I want except not to match <HeLLoWoRlD>123 , I had tried asserting a lookahead that says at least 1 digit is a prerequisite, that is(?=.*\d) but it still detects <HeLLoWoRlD>123, any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: There's something wrong with your assumptions here.